# If $n$ is a positive integer greater than 1 such that $3n+1$ is perfect square, then show that $n+1$ is the sum of three perfect squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a positive integer greater than 1 such that $3n+1$ is perfect square, then show that $n+1$ is the sum of three perfect squares.

My work:
$3n+1=x^2$
$3n+3=x^2+2$
$3(n+1)=x^2+2$
$(n+1)=\dfrac{x^2+2}{3}$

I have no clue what to do next. Please help!

Comment: where did you got his question? Some Olympiad?

Comment: no, not olympiad...i got it somewhere...don't remember where.had been trying since then without any luck!

Comment: I would suggest you to work out for $2n+1$ case first and then look for $3n+1$... i.e., $2n+1$ is a perfect square then $n+1$ is sum of two perfect squares....  let me tell you this is not so easy and this would take some time.... do not get frustrated... Good luck!

Comment: No, the cause for my frustration is, this problem was classified as 'easy'.

Comment: I am not aware of your level but this is a "Putnam practice level problem"... Good luck any how!

Comment: Thank you!...But, I am not aware of my level either!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are given that $3n+1 = a^2 $.

We want to show that $n+1$ is the sum of 3 perfect squares.

Note that $a$ is not a multiple of 3.

If $ a \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then observe that $9n+9 = 3a^2 + 6 = (a-1)^2 + (a-1)^2 + (a+2)^2$, and hence

$$ n+1 = \left( \frac{a-1}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{a-1}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{a+2}{3} \right)^2. $$

If $ a \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then observe that $9n+9 = 3a^2 + 6 = (a+1)^2 + (a+1)^2 + (a-2)^2$, and hence

$$ n+1 = \left( \frac{a+1}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{a+1}{3} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{a-2}{3} \right)^2 $$

Thus the result is true.

The motivation behind the solution is: We want to show that $n+1$ is the sum of 3 squares, and the only thing that we have to work with is $a^2$, and possibly things around it. Since $3a^2$ (the naive sum of 3 squares) is so close to $9n+9$, this suggests that we have some sort of wriggle room. Remembering that we have to account for the factor of 3 then greatly restricts our options.

---

As an extension, show that $n+3$ can also be written as the sum of 3 perfect squares, using a similar approach.

Comment: really neat...and great approach...thank you! can you suggest me some materials or books which will help me with these approaches for practice?

Answer (score 8):

If $\displaystyle 3n+1=a^2, (a,3)=1\implies a$ can be written as $\displaystyle3b\pm1$ where $b$ is an integer

So we have $\displaystyle 3n+1=(3b\pm1)^2\implies n=3b^2\pm2b$

$\displaystyle n+1=3b^2\pm2b+1=b^2+b^2+b^2\pm2b+1=b^2+b^2+(b\pm1)^2$

Comment: @Hawk, how about this method?

Comment: yes, this a good method too! It is just that you treated the residue modulo class before and Lin did after formulation! But one thing is good in this method...that is, I do not have to think about producing $9n+9$, which is a little complicated to think about in the first place!

Comment: @Hawk, another point: I didn't deal $a\equiv1,2\pmod 3$ separately

Comment: yes, that is what I said, you did not treat the residue modulo class directly!

Comment: @Hawk, sorry, I somehow missed that line:)

Comment: Oh no, nothing to be sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the answer : http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_as_Sum_of_Three_Squares

You need to prove that $n+1=\frac{x^2+2}{3}$ is not of the form $4^k(8m+7)$ for $k,m\in \mathbb{N}$ and its not that difficult to show this.

For Square modulo 8 we know that $x^2 =0,1,4 \mod{8}$, so $x^2 +2 =2,3,6 \mod{8}$.
Since $x^2 +2 =0 \mod{3}$ we obtain that $\frac{x^2 +2}{3} = 1,2,A \mod{8}$ where $A=\frac{2+8a}{3}$, $a$ positive integer. And $A=\psi \mod{8}$ namely, $2=3\psi \mod{8}$ with $\psi\in\{0,1,...,7\}$. The only possible value is $\psi=6$ hence $\frac{x^2 +2}{3} = 1,2,6 \mod{8}$.

If it was of that particular form then:

For $m=0$,$k=0$ it is equal to 7 modulo 8

For $m=0$,$k=1$ it is equal to 4 modulo 8

For $m=0$,$k=2$ it is equal to 0 modulo 8

For $m>0,k>2$ it is equal to 0 modulo 8
So you obtain a contradiction.

Comment: are you sure it is not difficult... I do not think so... :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik.Agreed!I cannot do it easily still now and I am trying!

Comment: Please show us your technique, you think it is easy. It will be easy for you to show!

Comment: I know it is not easy!  :D

Comment: Hope my answer is more helpful now.
Also I tried to help and my first thought was that is must be easy to show that last part. I might be wrong.
So I don't understand the frustration.

Comment: are you sure? because a number of the form $4^n(8m+7)$, put $n=1,m=0$,here the remainder is 4 not 7

Comment: Yes but you get again a contradiction. I edited my answer to include this.

Comment: take the case of $n=2$,the number is $0~mod 8$ for every m

Comment: Why is $x^2 + 3 = 0 \pmod{3}$? What about $x=0$? Furthermore, that's not how division works in modulo. You likely want $ 3^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Since $3n+1=x^2$ with $n$ positive integer how can $x=0$? Also $n+1=\frac{x^2+2}{3}$ isn't an integer?

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up the first part as I misread your statement. However, I still disagree with your division. It is possible that $\frac{x^2+2} { 3} \equiv 6 \pmod{8}$, which arises from $x^2 + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$. For example, when $x=4$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Now I think I understand what you mean. I skipped that part. I edited my answer.