# If $3n+1$ is a perfect square where $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$. Then how to prove that $n+1$ would be sum of $3$ perfect squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $3n+1$ is a perfect square where $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$. Then how to prove that $n+1$ would be sum of $3$ perfect squares?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633651/if-n-is-a-positive-integer-greater-than-1-such-that-3n1-is-perfect-square/634567#634567

Answer (score 0):

If $3n+1=m^2$, then $n+1=\frac{m^2+2}{3}$. We know that $m\not\equiv0\pmod{3}$

If $m\equiv1\pmod{3}$, then
$$
2\left(\frac{m-1}{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{m+2}{3}\right)^2=\frac{m^2+2}{3}
$$
If $m\equiv2\pmod{3}$, then
$$
2\left(\frac{m+1}{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{m-2}{3}\right)^2=\frac{m^2+2}{3}
$$