# Number theory problems.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is given: $3m+1=$perfect square. Express $m+1$, as the sum of $3$ perfect squares.

I tried to solve the problem by checking for odd and even values perfect squares $4k^2,{(2k+1)}^2$. I got somewhat convincing form of result from $3m+1={(2k+1)}^2$:

$m+1=\dfrac43(k^2)+\dfrac43(k)+1,$ so that $k$ must be a multiple of $3$,
 but I could not find the exact value of $k$, so that RHS is a perfect square.

as for the part $3m+1=4k^2$, I am hopeless.
Help please.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633651/if-n-is-a-positive-integer-greater-than-1-such-that-3n1-is-perfect-square/633841#633841)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3m + 1 = n^2$. This means: $n = 3k - 1$ or $n = 3k + 1$. If $n = 3k + 1$ then:

$m = \dfrac{n^2 - 1}{3}$, so $m + 1 = \dfrac{n^2 + 2}{3} = \dfrac{(3k + 1)^2 + 2}{3} = \dfrac{9k^2 + 6k + 3}{3} = 3k^2 + 2k + 1 = k^2 + k^2 + (k+1)^2$.

The other case is similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
3m + 1 = (3k  \pm 1)^2 = 9k^2 \pm 6k + 1
$$
implies
$$
m + 1 = \quad ?
$$
Now consider
$$
k^2 + k^2 + (k \pm 1)^2
$$