# Impossible form of a triangular number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, pythagorean-triples

Show that there are no positive integers $t,i,j$ with $j>i$ such that:

$\displaystyle \frac{t(t+1)}2=\frac{2i(j-i)j(j+i)}3$

If possible provide an elementary proof.

I believe the statement is correct as implied by the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487428/let-k-be-a-natural-number-then-3k1-4k1-and-6k1-cannot-all-be-squa), 
combined with [@WillJagy 's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1492889) and [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1561032) there.
But that question is also looking for a more elementary answer.

Note that both sides of the equation in the present problem are integers, indeed $\displaystyle\frac{t(t+1)}2$ is a triangular number, while if $3\not|\ i$ then $3|(j-i)j(j+i)$.

Edit. As shown by @ByronSchmuland in the comments, $t=15$, $j=5$, $i=4$ satisfy the above equation. Something must not be right with my other answer.

Comment: Try $i=4$, $j=5$, and $t=15$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland hey, it was not sup[posed to be *that* elementary :) so where did I go wrong with my other answer?

Comment: Sorry but the word "impossible" is like a red flag to me. ;) The first thing I do is to run a small program to look for counterexamples. I haven't looked carefully at the other answer yet.

Comment: Is the argument in the other answer reversible? If not, there is no contradiction here.