# Find the limit of the recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Definition  of  the  sequence **:**

$$a_1=a;\\a_2=b;\\$$ and $$\ \ \ a_{n+2}={{a_n+a_{n+1}}\over2}$$ for $n\geq 1$.

Find the limit of this  sequence in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Now in this case , taking $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$  on  both sides does not help at all . So what I did was try to find the $n$-th term  in therms of $a$ and $b$ and then take $n$ to $\infty.$

So , using the given recursion formula I wrote down like  $7$-$8$  terms, grouped them  in  various  ways  but  still  could  not  get the pattern of the $n$-th term.

Terribly  sorry  for  the  lack  of  work/context  in this post of mine but  I tried  for like an hour  to figure  things out  but can't really put  those  scribbles  down  here.

Please  give  me  some  hints  as  to  how  to find the answer .  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to solve linear recursions?  The characteristic equation for this system has two distinct real roots, so you can "easily" write down a closed form.

Comment: @lulu : I don't understand anything you said so I guess not. Could  you please help me a little   more  or , say  post an answer $?$

Comment: Try a hint first.  Linear recursions, like this one or like the Fibonacci sequence, can best be solved by "guessing" that the answer is of the form $a_n=\lambda^n$ and trying to find $\lambda$.  Sometimes, but not here, some additional steps are needed.  Here you just get a quadratic with two distinct real roots $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ so the general form is $a_n=A\lambda_1^n+B\lambda_2^n$

Comment: Here is a good reference for solving linear recursions:  http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM2.pdf

Comment: @lulu : I  don't understand anything  even  now . Whatever  linear algebra I have  learnt till  date  does not  include any such thing . Could  you  tell  me  what  book  or  what  topic/chapter  of a standard linear algebra book I should read to  know  these  things,please $?$

Comment: Here's another reference:  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial

Answer (score 3):

Different solution:

\begin{align}
2a_{n+2}&=a_{n+1}+a_n\\
2(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})&=-\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)\\
a_n-a_{n-1}&=-\frac12\left(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}\right)=\cdots=\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-2}\left(a_2-a_1\right)\\
\therefore a_n&=a_{n-1}+\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-2}\left(b-a\right)\\
a_{n-1}&=a_{n-2}+\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-3}\left(b-a\right)\\
&\cdots\\
a_2&=a_1+\left(-\frac12\right)^{0}\left(b-a\right)\\
\end{align}
Adding side by side,
\begin{align}
a_n&=a_1+(b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(-\frac12\right)^{k}\\
&=a+(b-a)\frac{1-\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}}{1-\left(-\frac12\right)}\\
&=a+\frac23(b-a)\left(1-\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{a+2b}{3}+\frac{2(a-b)}{3}\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}
You can see the outcome is exactly same as other solutions.

But hopefully you'll be able to find where the $\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}$ is coming from.

Comment: Nice, elementary, and no magic involved.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks, marty.

Comment: Very slick solution. I like this method a lot.

Comment: I generalized this for $ca_{n-1}+(1-c)a_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{3}a+\frac{2}{3}b+\left(\frac{4}{3}b-\frac{4}{3}a\right)\times\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$$

Comment: And  how  do  I  decide  that  $?$

Comment: This is obvious to anyone for whom it is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&2a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}-a_n=0\\
&2\alpha^2-\alpha-1=0\quad\rightarrow\quad\alpha=1,-\frac12\\
&a_n=A\cdot1^{n-1}+B\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}\\
\end{align}
Using initial conditions,
\begin{align}
&A+B=a,\quad A-\frac B2=b\\
&\rightarrow A=\frac{a+2b}3,\quad B=\frac{2(a-b)}3\\
&a_n=\frac{a+2b}3+\frac{2(a-b)}3\left(-\frac12\right)^{n-1}\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{a+2b}3\\
\end{align}

Comment: How  did  you  come  up  with  that  $2\alpha ^2 -\alpha -1=0$  after  the  first  step  $?$

Comment: I got two roots ($1$, $-\frac12$) and then made up the expression for $a_n$ that is $a_n = c_0\cdot \alpha_0^n + c_1\cdot \alpha_1^n$ ($\alpha_0=1$ and $\alpha_1=-\frac12$ in our case). In my answer I used $n-1$ instead of $n$ to make later calculations easier. You can google "generating function for sequence" and can find information.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a closed form for the individual terms of the recurrence, you can use the method of generating functions. This first step places your sequence as the terms of a power series $G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$, and then you generate a separate representation using the recursion. It's a long process but very powerful. It's real strength comes from combinatorics, but it can solve linear recurrences well.

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n = ax + bx^2 + \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n x^n$$
$$= ax + bx^2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+2} x^{n+2}$$
$$= ax + bx^2 + \frac x2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1} x^{n+1} + \frac{x^2}2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} x^{n}$$
$$= ax + bx^2 + \frac x2 \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} x^{n} - ax\right) + \frac{x^2}2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n} x^{n}.$$

Thus recognizing $G(x)$ as the series on the right, we have
$$G(x)= ax + bx^2 + \frac x2 \left(G(x) - ax\right) + \frac{x^2}2 G(x).$$ Thus solving for $G(x)$ we find:

$$G(x)(1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2})=ax + (b-\frac{a}{2})x^2$$

and

$$G(x) = \frac{2ax}{2-x-x^2} + \frac{(2b-a)x^2}{2-x-x^2}.$$

Using partial fraction decomposition we get:

$$G(x) = (2ax + (2b-a)x^2) \left( \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac x 2\right)} + \frac13 \frac{1}{1-x} \right)$$

Now applying geometric series identities:

$$G(x) = (2ax + (2b-a)x^2) \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} + \frac13\right) x^n $$

Manipulating series:

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2a \left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} + \frac13\right) x^{n+1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2b-a)\left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} + \frac13\right) x^{n+2}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2a \left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} + \frac13\right) x^{n} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (2b-a)\left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{2^{n-2}} + \frac13\right) x^{n}$$

$$=a + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left[ 2a \left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} + \frac13\right) + (2b-a)\left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{2^{n-2}} + \frac13\right) \right] x^n$$

Thus since $G$ is a power series centered about zero, its coefficients are uniquely determined. For $n \ge 2$ we have: $$a_n = \left[ 2a \left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}} + \frac13\right) + (2b-a)\left( \frac{1}{6}  \frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{2^{n-2}} + \frac13\right) \right]$$

now as $n \to \infty$ we are left with $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 2a \cdot \frac13 + (2b-a) \cdot \frac13 = \frac{1}{3}a + \frac{2}{3} b$.

Comment: @user118494 Your comments posed to the other answers are addressed in this answer. The appearance of the characteristic equation $2x^2-x-1=0$ is important in factoring the denominator before applying the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: This method will always work for linear recurrences. It just take a bit of time. With practice and observation, you will realize how to move from the long winded generating function derivation to the quicker answers others gave.

Comment: Certainly, though, generating functions aren't the only way to go about it. There are many linear algebraic methods that can solve the problem. The nice approach of generating functions only require some knowledge of power series obtained in Calculus 2. It is fairly tedious.

Answer (score 0):

We will try a form for the solution with some unknown parameters, and then see if we can find parameters that make it work. For example, let us guess that

$$
a_n = Ad^n
$$

for some constant numbers $d$ and $A$. Then we also need:

$$
a_{n+1} = Ad^{(n+1)}
$$

$$
a_{n+2} = Ad^{(n+2)}
$$

Then plug into our equation:

$$
Ad^{(n+2)} = \frac{Ad^{(n+1)}+Ad^n}{2}
$$

Every term is divisible by $Ad^n$, so cancelling that everywhere we get
$$
d^2 = \frac{d+1}{2}
$$

We can see that the recurrence relation is true if we can find a $d$ that satisfies this quadratic equation. Rearranging, we see that it is

$$
d^2-\frac{d}{2}-\frac{1}{2} = 0
$$

This quadratic factors nicely into

$$
(d-1)(d+1/2) = 0
$$

which is true when $d=1$ or $d=-1/2$. Now what this tells us is that if we take

$$
a_n = A1^n = A
$$

or

$$
a_n = A(-1/2)^n,
$$

we have a solution to the original problem. Recall that $A$ was an arbitrary constant that has not been determined yet, so it is possible that it is actually two different constants between the two cases above. To account for this, we write the second constant as $B$, giving two independent solutions

$$
a_n = A,\;\text{or}\;a_n=B(-1/2)^n
$$

Now, we can see that plugging in either solution solves the recurrence. What about their sum? You can work out that the sum of the two solutions is also a solution, so consider

$$
a_n = A + B(-1/2)^n
$$

This is the general solution. We figured out what the $d$ value was, now we have to figure out the $A$ and $B$ constants. Fortunately, we have some additional constraints:
$$
a_1 = a,\;a_2=b
$$
You should be able to take it from here to solve for $A$ and $B$, following what the other answers show.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing Kay K's solution:

If
$a_{n+1}
=ca_n+(1-c)a_{n-1}
$
where
$0 < c < 1$,
then
$a_{n+1}-a_n
=-(1-c)(a_n-a_{n-1})
=r(a_n-a_{n-1})
$,
where
$r = -(1-c)
$.

By induction,
$a_{n+1}-a_n
=r^k(a_{n-k+1}-a_{n-k-2})
$.

Setting
$k = n-1$,
$a_{n+1}-a_n
=r^{n-1}(a_{2}-a_{1})
=sr^{n-1}
$,
where
$s
=a_{2}-a_{1}
$.

Summing this from
$n=1$ to $m-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
a_m-a_1
&=s\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} r^{n-1}\\
&=s\sum_{n=0}^{m-2} r^{n}\\
&=s\frac{1-r^{m-1}}{1-r}\\
&=(a_{2}-a_{1})\frac{1-(c-1)^{m-1}}{c}\\
&=(a_{2}-a_{1})\frac1{c}-\frac{(c-1)^{m-1}}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_m
=a_1+(a_{2}-a_{1})\frac1{c}-\frac{(c-1)^{m-1}}{c}
=\frac{a_{2}+(1-c)a_{1}}{c}-\frac{(c-1)^{m-1}}{c}
$.

Therefore,
since
$|c-1| < 1$,
$\lim_{m \to \infty}a_m
=\frac{a_{2}+(1-c)a_{1}}{c}$.

If $c = \frac12$,
this is
$\frac{a_{2}+\frac12 a_{1}}{\frac12}
=2a_{2}+a_{1}
$.

Note that
the characteristic polynomial
is
$0
=x^2-cx-(1-c)
=(x-1)(x-(c-1))
$.
This shows that
the roots
are always nice.

Comment: Thanks, Marty. Actually this method can be applied to almost all the cases. One example is here  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562657/how-to-get-the-binet-form-for-the-sequence-1-5-45-441-4361/1562691#1562691